# Unfortunately, the package bibtex8bit could not be installed

Tags: bibtex, citing

I'm currently working on my master's thesis and somehow my program doesn't want to read my literature.bib file. I kinda tried everything regarding citation styles, URL change etc. but nothing worked. Now I saw this error message coming up in my log-file and I'm not sure how to solve it.

**Error Message:**
Unfortunately, the package bibtex8bit could not be installed. Please check the log file: C:\Users****\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\bibtex8.log
Process ended with errors

Thank you in advance.
Best wishes.

Jannis

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! How did you try to install it? Also: why not compile you bibliography you biblatex + biber?

Comment: Hey Bernard :) thank you for the fast response. I received a template from my university and i thought that everything would be included in there. And the only thing i did with LaTeX was to create a bibtech file, which i wanted to include as my citation source. I tried to find out how to install bibtex8bit manually, but i couldnt figure out how to do that. And what do you mean by compiling my bibligraphy+biblatex+biber?

Comment: Biblatex is easier to modify than a bibtex style file (it uses a latex syntax) and  biber is a modern bibliography engine, which understands utf8. Another question: why didn't you install bibtex8bit with MiKTeX Package Manager?

Comment: Hey :) i reinstalled my MikTeX Package Manager and now the installation of the bibtex8bit worked. But somehow my Program now shows errors, which werent marked before. And still my bibtex-File of my literature cannot be read.

Comment: In this case, you should post a minimal, yet complete, code reproducing the problem.

Comment: I made a new post regarding  my problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/616334/literature-bibtex-integration-siunitx-package-decimalsymbol-error