# Literature BibTeX-Integration & Siunitx-Package 'decimalsymbol' error

Tags: siunitx

I have made a post regarding a problem of not be able to include my literature.bib File in my master thesis due to a problem with my bibtex8bit-package ([Unfortunately, the package bibtex8bit could not be installed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/616200/unfortunately-the-package-bibtex8bit-could-not-be-installed)). Now I reinstalled MikteX as well as TeXStudio and the Bibtex8bit problem disappeared. Still my literatur-file cannot be read as shown for the shortage of my code. Also I suddenly get new errors regarding my ,,siunitx-package'' which I've never seen before. It would help me a lot, if you'd give me some advice.

Thank you so much!

**CODE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,titlepage]{scrbook}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
%Codierung
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%Hyperref
\usepackage{hyperref}
%Zitation von Referenzen
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage[super,square,sort&compress]{natbib}
%Einbindung von Graphiken
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%Erweiterung von Tabellen
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%Mathematische Pakete
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%SI_Einheiten
\usepackage[locale = DE, decimalsymbol=comma,exponent-product = \cdot]{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = DE, per-mode=reciprocal-positive-first}
%Chemische Pakete
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}

%Newcommands
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    
\begin{itemize}
    \item Preparation of $\SI{5}{molar}$ Nitric Acid solution with distilled water
    \item Addition of AC to be treated into distillation flask at the rate of $1:50$ [\gram:\milli\liter solution]
        
    \end{itemize}

Rivka B. Fidel and David A. Laird \cite{Fidel.2013b}, 

\chapter*{List of Abbreviations}

\newpage
\bibliography{literature}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
Package keyvalue Error: Unknown option 'decimalsymbol' for package siunitx. \ProcessKeysOptions { siunitx }
Undefined control sequence. ...llation flask at the rate of $1:50$ [\gram
Citation `Fidel.2013b' on page 1 undefined
There were undefined citations.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Welcome! FYI, you can upvote and accept helpful answers so that others see what solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The option `decimalsymbol` is from version 1 of `siunitx`. In version 2, these options were available for upgraders, but they were not carried forward to the current release (v3). You want `quantity-product = {,}`.

(Note: v2 was released over 10 years ago - this was not a quick change.)

Comment: There's a second error in the OP's code: `\gram:\milli\liter` causes a crash. I'm surmiising the OP meant to write `\si{\gram\per\milli\liter}`.

Comment: Hey Jospeh, thank you so much for the input!! i just changed all the units and that worked out! I still have these errors regarding the siunitx. How shall i configure this? Did you mean mean to put the package data like that?                                                                         \usepackage[locale = DE, decimalsymbol=comma,exponent-product = {,}]{siunitx}

Comment: @JannisSchey - What Joseph was saying is that you have to replace `decimalsymbol=comma` with `quantity-product = {,}`.

Comment: @Mico Oh wow.. im so sorry that was kinda stupid.. Thanks alot!! Now it worked out :)