# Differentiate package parameters for different versions of package

Tags: parameters, portability

I have 2 versions of TeXLive:

- 2020 at home (as far as I remember)
- 2021 at work

I have a document with string:

```
\usepackage[group-separator = \;, decimalsymbol=comma]{siunitx}
```

It works at home, but at work it breaks with an error:

```
Package keyvalue Error: Unknown option 'decimalsymbol' for package siunitx.
```

Then I change it to:

```
\usepackage[group-separator = \;]{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}
```

it starts working at work. Is it possible to create a portable version of document that will work on both systems?

Comment: No guarantee but what about quantity-product? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/616334/literature-bibtex-integration-siunitx-package-decimalsymbol-error

Comment: If everything fails there's still the option of conditional on texlive version https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96570/automatically-determine-which-texlive-version-is-being-used

Comment: I assume that you're free to use your home machine as you wish, so why not upgrade? TeX Live released version 2022 last month. If I remember correctly, `siunitx` did go through some changes recently.

Comment: Can you add `\listfiles` to both setups and edit in the version of `siunitx` to the question: I suspect you have v2 and v3, but the option you using suggests v1 (from 2008!).

Comment: @JosephWright I'll try the new option on home machine. TeXLive is not that old there.

Comment: @JosephWright At last I ran the `\listfiles` command. The result at home is: `siunitx.sty    2020/02/25 v2.8b A comprehensive (SI) units package`

Comment: @JosephWright Hello there?